# Best new cryptocurrencies to mine using CPU

Tags: cpu-mining, cryptocurrency-comparison, cryptonight

I’ve been mining LiteCoins since it was worth around £40. Now it’s worth £200 pounds and I have less than 0.01 LTC and I cannot withdraw any of what I earned from my pool. This balance is very low because I was mining on a laptop which wasn’t the most efficient.

Now I have my hands on about 20 Raspberry Pi’s, half are model b+ and the other half are just model b.

What will be the most easiest to mine cryptocurrencies? I have researched on Bytecoin which uses the cryptonight algorithm, but I also heard that the creators of Bytecoin has already mined about 80% of it.

Is there another cryptocurrency out there that can be mined using a CPU without being disadvantaged from the people who are using GPU’s or ASIC miners? I don’t need the cryptocurrency to be worth a lot of real dollars or pounds, but it needs to have to potential to be worth a lot in the future and also needs to be easily mined using a CPU.

Thanks,

Sid.

Comment: Hi @SidS .. I'm posting this as a comment because finding an answer may be difficult as it is so subjective. I'll just give you an "if it were me" .. I'd probably just mine Monero SOLO ... each Pi will cost < $5 year (guessing 0.15KW/hr) and you'll have difficulty finding a profitable coin. Even is electricity isn't a concern, the performance would likely be hard to reach minimum payouts at any real pool that doesn't support SOLO mining. You are in the realm of pure luck and lottery in my estimation. You have to consider that time raises difficulty levels so it will get worse not better.

Comment: @Mark is right, you will really be playing the lottery with this one.  Pi's will be super slow to chew through hashes as it is, but on top of that the model b and b+, as far as I know, do not have aes-ni... which will slow any proc down in terms of h/s.  An Rpi3 is the best bet of any that I have seen and even then the max h/s that I've seen anyone post on one of those has been 20 h/s (https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7n6lnt/raspberry_pi_3_mining_review/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're asking is what to expect when CPU mining on approx 20 Raspberry Pis that you have spare. I can help you with some numbers as I've demo'd it on a Raspberry Pi 3.

One Raspberry Pi 3 can achieve 7.5H/s per CPU thread. (The raspberry Pi 3 has four available.)

For stability and so as not to over-temp the Raspberry Pi I used 3 threads in my test, and was pool mining using lucasjones cpu-multi miner and sending solutions to http://minexmr.com/ pool.

The Pool reported a hashrate of 25H/s for the one Raspberry Pi using three threads.

Assuming $0.10 for electricity the one Pi would yield 0.01XMR per month, costing $0.72 for electicity. And an estimated profit yearly of $15.02 at current difficulty and price.
This data is all taken from https://www.monero.how/monero-mining-calculator using the Pooled mining calcualtor. The Pi consumes 10W of power, (5v x 2A).

---

So for 20 Raspberry Pis expect 0.11XMR per month, an extra $14.40 for electricity and 300.44USD per year profit.

The Pool http://minexmr.com/ auto pays out at 0.5XMR, but manual payments can be requested at any point but incur a 0.004XMR fee. Pool also charges 1% usage fee.

Hope that answers your question. For Monero anyway.
It cannot be stated enough though that any long term estimates on price/profit and difficulty over 4 weeks into the future are wildly inaccurate. Don't mine this for an investment, do it as a hobby. Raspberry Pi's are not well suited to this task. But of all the currencies Monero is one of the better suited to CPU mining.
If you want to invest, probably best sell the Raspberry Pi's and buy Monero with the money.

Edit: For your convienience/give it a try...
This runs a script to install the miner and configure it.
On the Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo git clone https://github.com/shingolavine/raspberrypimining.git
cd raspberrypimining
sudo ./minerSetup.sh
cd cpuminer-multi
```

Example Run/configuration:

./minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://pool.address.xxx:port -u YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS -p x

Those commands will install the lucasjones cpu-multi miner and start mining with 3 threads as default. It is noted and is a known bug by users that hash-rate will display as 0 until a valid share is found.